# env->ExceptionCheck() in JNA

Tags: jna

I am using JNA in my project and my Java JNA Callbacks throw exception in some cases. I want to know from C/C++ code an exception was thrown by last calbback method call. In JNI, one can do it using env->ExceptionCheck() but could not find any equivalent in JNA.

Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Comment: i looked at callback.c and found that it clears the exception after method invoke (*env)->ExceptionClear(env)

Answer (score 0):

The native code calling your callback certainly has no expectation that a Java exception will be raised.  There is no guarantee that a JNA callback will be invoked from a containing JVM context.  Even if it were, you'd have to establish an out of band channel to pass the exception from the callback to the JVM further up the stack, since you have no guarantees about the calling C code.

Assuming you have Java code -> C code -> callback, I'd recommend you catch all your callback's exceptions, then put them somewhere for the calling Java code to examine after the call.

You could make this happen under the covers with an `InvocationMapper`, which basically lets you capture and/or modify the results of an interface-mapped call, but it's probably easier just to be explicit about it and wrap the whole thing in a utility function.

For example:

```
public interface MyLibrary extends Library {
    MyLibrary INSTANCE = (MyLibrary)Native.loadLibrary();
    interface MyCallback extends Callback {
        void invoke();
    }
    void myFunction(MyCallback callback);
}
```

Then you provide a utility wrapper:

```
public void myFunction(final MyCallback callback) {
    final List<Exception> exceptions = new List<Exception>();
    MyLibrary.INSTANCE.myFunction(new MyCallback() {
        public void invoke() {
            try {
                callback.invoke();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                exceptions.add(e);
            }
        }
    });
    if (exceptions.size() > 0) {
        // ...
    }
}
```